# topology sorting

Tags: algorithm, sorting, graph-algorithm

Given a DAG with N nodes, each node has a value (e.g., 0.2, 0.5, 1.3, 0.1...). I want to sort the vertices into a chain.  The difficulty is that there is an objective function when sorting the nodes.

For example, the chain is x---> y --->z ---> w. Each link has a weight, for (x,y) weight= x, link (y,z) weight = xy,  link (z,w) weight = xyz and so on.

The objective function is to minimize the sum (here for the chain : x+xy+xyz) of all links weight.

I have been thinking about it. But I have no idea now. Is anyone can give some ideas on the algorithm design or the complexity proof of the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't greedy work for this? Since it's topological sort, each subproblem is independent of the parent problem.

Comment: No. I don't think so.  Here is a counterexample :  the DAG consists of two separate chain: 1.2---> 0.5  and 1.1--->1.001.  The optimized sorted chain should be 1.2----> 0.5---->1.1---->1.001.  Maybe for one greed algorithm the chain should be: 1.1----> 1.001---->1.2 ---> 0.5 ( smallest vertex first). Could you give more idea on the greedy algorithm?

Comment: Is the node value important at all, or just the link weight?

Comment: The link weight is computed by the product of vertex value.

Comment: N will be small in my case (maybe dozens of nodes). I want to design a general algorithm, no matter how many nodes in the graph. I am not sure if it is a NP hard problem. I think it's a complex one.

Comment: @user2585677 You greedily choose the next state, not the next node. In effect, it's just Dijkstra's on the state space where the distance is the marginal cost of the next node. This should run in O(n log n) where n is the number of states, so O(v*2^v), which is fine for dozens of nodes, but doesn't work for general n.

Comment: Also, your counterexample contradicts your problem statement, because you defined the weight of link (z,w) as xyz, so the output is just the sum, but I see that you probably meant that the weight is z and the cost of choosing that link is the product of the previous weights.

Comment: Does the DAG have any special structure?

Comment: @kevmo314 Yes, I greedily choose a vertex with smallest value in each step. For the counterexample, I just gave two possible sorted chains. The first one is the optimized one based on the objective functions.  Chain 1 (started from 1.2) cost = 1.2 + 1.2 *0.5 + 1.2*0.5*1.1 = 2.46    ;   Chain 2 (started from 1.1) cost = 1.1 + 1.1*1.001 + 1.1*1.001*1.2 = 3.52242.

Comment: @David Eisenstat Not exactly. For some specific cases, it may have special structures. I want to design a general algorithm. And I also wonder if it is a NP problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the algorithm to which kevmo314 alluded, implemented in Python. Probably it should be reimplemented in C, with bit-wise operations replacing the set operations.

We can rewrite the objective

```
x + x*y + x*y*z = x*(1 + y*(1 + z)),
```

so assuming that all of the weights are positive, the overall objective is monotone in the subproblem objectives, which allows dynamic programming.

```
def optimal_order(predecessors_map, weight_map):
    vertices = frozenset(predecessors_map.keys())
    memo_map = {frozenset(): (0, [])}
    return optimal_order_helper(predecessors_map, weight_map, vertices, memo_map)


def optimal_order_helper(predecessors_map, weight_map, vertices, memo_map):
    if vertices in memo_map:
        return memo_map[vertices]
    possibilities = []
    for v in vertices:
        if any(u in vertices for u in predecessors_map[v]):
            continue
        sub_obj, sub_order = optimal_order_helper(predecessors_map, weight_map, vertices - frozenset({v}), memo_map)
        possibilities.append((weight_map[v] * (1.0 + sub_obj), [v] + sub_order))
    best = min(possibilities)
    memo_map[vertices] = best
    return best


print(optimal_order({'u': [], 'v': ['u'], 'w': [], 'x': ['w']}, {'u': 1.2, 'v': 0.5, 'w': 1.1, 'x': 1.001}))
```

Comment: Smart , Excellent!! You help me see the nature and context of the problem.